# Which file transfer protocols support server-side copying?

Tags: copying, protocol

I'm wondering which file transfer protocols available on Linux support server-side copying (and doesn't internally download and reupload files). The simplest use case I have is for copying large files (such as VMs) from one directory to another on the same share.

I know Samba 4.1.0 recently implemented support for FSCTL_SRV_COPYCHUNK in the SMB2 protocol, but as far as I know, no client-side tool/file manager supports this yet ([link](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy)). I've also looked at AFP, but the only two Linux tools for mounting AFP shares are `gvfs-afp` and `afpfs-ng` and neither are too great. afpfs-ng is unmaintained and doesn't cooperate well with netatalk (segfaults), while gvfs-afp has very low throughput compared to afpfs-ng when it works. **Update:** it looks like the next version of NFS might support this too.

Are there any other protocols that support server-side copying?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need this rarely or often? Used by users of operators? If rarely or operators, I'd just ssh to the machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, AFP supports server side copies. The latest unreleased version of gvfs contains a number of improvements to gvfsd-afp to make it more reliable and faster. In my tests, it is able to get about 70MB/s for a large transfer on 1GBE and is able to duplicate a directory of 10000 files in 11 seconds which is not too bad. If server side copies are important and you don't want to be logged into a terminal, this is what I'd recommend to use.

We also plan on adding server side copy support for gvfsd-smb soon, but who knows when "soon" may be...

(Disclaimer, I help maintain gvfs.)

Comment: Many thanks! I'll compile gvfs from git and give it a try. By the way, do you know if Samba 4 supports server-side copy yet or does it require a Windows server?

Comment: I just compiled gvfs from git master (`232d6d76029dc1cbc0c76c2459f9db26b7717d28`) and AFP is working beautifully now. Server-side copies work and the throughput is on par with gvfs-smb and sftp (over 802.11ac). Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome :-) Yeah, the Samba 4.1 _server_ does support server-side copy afaik. The Samba client tools don't. I think support has been added to the cifs kernel module to do a server-side copy but a special ioctl needs to be used to make use of it which most programs don't make use of.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by Ross Lagerwall, Samba 4.1+ SMB2 server-side copy support can be utilized by the Linux CIFS kernel client (cifs.ko) via the CIFS_IOC_COPYCHUNK_FILE ioctl.

The [Cloner](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/xfs/xfstests-dev.git/tree/src/cloner.c) utility shipped with fstests can be used to issue the ioctl on cifs.ko SMB2 mount points. Work on smbclient support is also in progress.

One benefit of the Samba server-side copy implementation is that it can be used atop a Btrfs filesystem to perform near-instantaneous copy / deduplication of file data, as demonstrated in [this performance comparison](http://youtu.be/vFSjXoHg_Z4).